# What's causing my SocketException: Connection reset?

Tags: java, sockets, connection, socketexception, connection-reset

In any iteration within the while, a SocketException: Connection reset is generated. can someone give me some suggestions?

```
    logger.info("Start send xml");
    StringBuilder bld = new StringBuilder();

    try (Socket socket = new Socket(ipAddress,port)){

        socket.setSoTimeout(600000);
        OutputStream output = socket.getOutputStream();
        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(output, true);
        writer.println(xml);
        writer.flush();

        InputStream input = socket.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
        String line;

        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
            bld.append(line);


        writer.close();
        reader.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        logger.error("Error sending the XML");
        logger.error(e.getMessage());
        throw new SendXMLException(e.getMessage());
    }

    logger.info("End Send xml -> " + bld.toString());
    return bld.toString();
```

Comment: That usually means a network problem. Double check that `ipAddress`:`port` is actually listening. You can verify with a tool like telnet: `telnet <ipAddress> <port>`

Comment: Several reasons a `SocketException.class` is thrown [Socket Exception SE 8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/SocketException.html). "error creating or accessing a Socket." Which Java Version are you using?

Comment: Also it helps to have the whole set of code in a working manner. More likely to get a good response when a person can easily take your code and paste it to run it.

Comment: Take a look here for examples of some newer java ways Java 7 using NIO. [Java Code Geeks](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/nio/java-nio-large-file-transfer-tutorial/)

Comment: Server closes your connection.

Comment: @dontocsatathe server is always active
@ Mr00Anderson Java 8